# C# Is it possible to restrict a Generic Abstract class single parameter to two different user defined types?

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, abstract

First of all I want to thank all those who help, I am not very good coder and I barely started coding in C#. My objective is to develop kinda IDE for signal processing and hide most of the details of coding

```
abstract public class DSPdata<DSPtype> 
        where DSPtype : DSPComplex, DSPReal
{
    // Restrict DSPtype to be real or complex
}

public class DSPReal : DSPdata<DSPReal>
{
    // Implement functionality of DSPReal 
}

public class DSPComplex : DSPdata<DSPComplex>
{
}
```

I got this reference but I am not very clear.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx
 I do apologize for my writing ENGLISH and CODING. I hope I can get some help
Best regards, C

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: @shole It's the current generic constraint that's not working. A generic constraint in C# can have only one class name to be restricted to. It however can have multiple interfaces which is a solution suggested by Cameron Vetter below.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, what you are trying to do is possible.  Your implementation actually does something slightly different.  It restricts the generic type DSPtype to be a type that is both DSPComplex AND DSPReal.  I believe what you want to do is restrict the generic type DSPtype to be either DSPComplex OR DSPReal.

To do this you should use an interface to do something like this:

```
abstract public class DSPdata< DSPtype > 
    where DSPtype : IDSPdata {
   // Restrict DSPtype to be real or complex
}

public class DSPReal : IDSPdata
   // Implement functionality of DSPReal 
}

public class DSPComplex : IDSPdata
{
}

public interface IDSPdata 
{
    // Add whatever must appear in DSPtype for it to work here
}
```

Comment: If we go by the question from the question title, this does not do what the OP wants - anyone could add their own, third, implementation of `IDSPdata` and thus violate the intended constraint of the "two different user defined types".

Answer (score 0):

While what Cameron said is correct, remember that C# does not allow multi-inheritance, therefore type constraint on more than one type (not interface!) is not allowed. Type constraint only allows to define constraints as conjunction. Of course, you can have multiple interfaces in the constraint, C# allows the type to implement any number of interfaces.

Comment: "multiple interfaces in the constraint" - but then the concrete type must implement all of them (i.e. AND), while the OP asked about one of them (i.e. OR).

Comment: Correct, that is why I wrote that the constraints are used as conjunction. Alternative of types/interfaces is not allowed in type constraints.

Answer (score 0):

Once way to implement indirectly, is to introduce an internal constructor in the base class, in combination with a slightly modified generic constraint.

With an internal constructor, you cannot create an instance in another assembly. So, if you can define the `DSPData<T>` type and the `DSPReal` and `DSPComplex` types in the same separate assembly, then you can prevent any other type from being created in other assemblies.

```
// Assembly A
public abstract class DSPData<DSPType>
    where DSPType : DSPData<DSPType>
{
    internal DSPData() { }
}

public class DSPReal : DSPData<DSPReal>
{
    public DSPReal() { }
}

public class DSPComplex : DSPData<DSPComplex>
{
    public DSPComplex() { }
}

// Assembly B, references assembly A
// Doesn't compile
public class DSPTest : DSPData<DSPTest>
{
    public DSPTest() { }
}
```